# Visual Studio Code - Problemas con etiquetas input

Tags: html

Estaba escribiendo en un archivo HTML una etiqueta input para hacer un registro a un newsletter. Coloqué el código así: `<input type="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">`. No sé que ha ocurrido que no me permite colocar texto en ese input y ni siquiera cambia el cursor. Si alguien sabe qué hacer, me haría un favor.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer esa línea de código se ve correcta. Quizás tengas una etiqueta abierta más arriba. Yo la probé en mi equipo y funciona.

```
        <form action="#">
            <label for="email">Correo:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
        </form>
```

Comment: hm... probé el código que enviaste, pero el problema persiste, no sé que hacer.